# Need MySQL query that gets orders from main table, then a count of individual items associated with it as well as total rows from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I really need a MySQL query that gets orders from main table, then a count of individual items associated with it as well as total rows from another table.

So I have the following structure:

```
db.Orders
id | order_number | date_worked

1 | 1234 | 2014-09-17
2 | 1235 | 2014-09-17
3 | 1236 | 2014-09-17
4 | 1237 | 2014-09-17


db.OrdersItems
id | order_number_id | item_id

1 | 1234 | widget1
2 | 1234 | widget1
3 | 1234 | widget2
4 | 1234 | widget2
5 | 1234 | widget2
6 | 1235 | widget4
7 | 1235 | widget4
8 | 1236 | widget4
9 | 1236 | widget1
10| 1237 | widget1
```

An order can have multiple SKUs and multiple lines per SKU per order. So what I am looking for and just can't figure out, is how to get the following:

order_number | count of individual skus from db.OrdersItems for order_number_id | total row count for order_number_id

ex.

```
1234 | 2 skus | 5 lines
1235 | 1 skus | 2 lines
1236 | 2 skus | 2 lines
1237 | 1 skus | 1 lines
```

Comment: "I really need a MySQL query that...". Good for you, go on and write it! [**Have you tried anything?**](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Barranka, I had attempted, but knowing that it was completely wrong, I forwent posting it in an effort to minimize confusion. I logically laid out the question and in turn received a great response. It may have been somewhat bad etiquette, but the question and now answer will hopefully help someone else in the future without having to wade through muddled code of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe you are after ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/271f9/2/0)):

```
SELECT o.order_number, COUNT(DISTINCT i.item_id) AS SkuCnt, COUNT(*) AS LineCnt
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN OrdersItems i ON o.order_number = i.order_number_id
GROUP BY o.order_number
```

Comment: This is perfect and you were super fast. Thanks so much. I was trying to put select statements in count()s for some reason. Head isn't working right today. Will mark as answer as soon as it lets me.